# Why do most broken screens become greener and greener?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I have experienced many screen failures, from CRT's, to modern various flat screens to modern smartphone touchscreens etc... But why do most of them when they fail either(unless it was physical puncturing):

- get green artifacts
- get green lines
- become greener or in extreme cases:
- become different shades of green

If we assume they have a sort of RGB system behind them(I am no expert at screen technology), why is it almost always that the red and blue that fail first?

Comment: What you describe doesn't happen LCD monitors/displays/etc

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your claim that screens become greener and greener when they break?

Comment: Only ~20 years of my own experience, plus me being in electrical engineering first and then moving on to IT/CS.

Comment: @Ramhound not an LCD, but I saw it on a TFT flatscreen.

Comment: @Ramhound I also saw it on my own Samsung Galaxy S3 with an AMOLED after water damage.

Comment: Damage to the screen might produce weird lines or random colors. But LCD screens don't change colors as they age, it is the backlights that changes colors. Before LED backlights, LCDs used fluorescent bulbs. The bulbs would age and get dimmer and redder. So, in fact, old LCDs turn pink as they age. Modern LED backlights do not have that problem. Whatever you are describing is not fact based. Your LCD is damaged.

Comment: @MarioKamenjak - Anything can happen if you introduce water damaged to something like a AMOLED display.  You can't compare what happens to a CRT monitor to what happens to a AMOLED display after you introduce water damage to it's circuit.

Comment: I'd venture this belongs more on something like Engineering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything video related has an RGB system behind, but those cases are completely different things.

For old CRTs, sometimes red emitters used to just consume enough not to be powerful enough. The red became darker and darker until gone completely. The result was a greenish image. No red means everything from red to radioactive green is displayed as something between black and green. 
Green survives the longest because green is the easiest to obtain compared to red and blue.

Green lines (some types of them) can happen due to damage to the vertical or horizontal scan problems. This can happen to CRTs and some LCDs.

Green artifacts are due mostly to damage to GPU or the video memory, they are unrelated to the screen itself. And there's usually magenta too, in such cases.